# Contact Form 7: Email custom HTML inputs or make a field readonly

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am trying to email a custom input

```
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" class="wpcf7-text" readonly="readonly" />
```

I tried `[total]` but it does not work. Or isit possible to make a field readonly with WPCF7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact form 7 is one of my favorite plugins , now after I've said that you can either create your own module to add a filed of "readonly" by following this tutorial http://blog.ekynoxe.com/2010/09/06/extending-contact-form-7/

or maybe even digging through [Contact Form 7 Modules](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-modules/) plugin to see how to add new modules,
but a much easier solution would be to create a regular text filed and use JQuery to add the readonly attribute

`$('#inputId').attr('readonly', true);`